# Oracle - AURORA$JIS$UTILITY$

Tags: oracle

Doing some archiving/deleting of some uncommonly used databases on an Oracle server.

Has anyone heard of **AURORA$JIS$UTILITY$** and what is its purppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is one of the Jserv accounts created automatically when Oracle Servlet Engine (OSE) was installed in an old version - it hasn't been supported form some time (since 8i?). Not sure what it was used for within that though.